# Back button in safari browser broken

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari

I've read a couple of questions here about back buttons being incompatible with Safari , but I didn't encounter my specific type of problem. Right now I have

```
<a id="back_btn" onclick="" href="javascript:Application.goBack();void(0);">
```

What I try to accomplish is having a back button. This works on all devices except Safari (new versions, for instance I am testing on 9.0). I've already tried with:

```
<a id="back_btn" onclick="" href="javascript:history.go(-1);">
```

and many other variations I've read about in other similar questions but they doesn't seem to work either.

Now here is the catch. All this is happening in iframe and url is not changing at all (while the content does (as on other browsers) ). I've also noticed that first time I hit the button it does something, because the back button from browser becomes active , but the thing is that the content is not changed. Its like it tries to go back (and probably does) , but it doesn't change the content of the iframe.

EDIT : I might have found whats the problem , but I am not entirely sure how I can workaround to fix it.
The thing is that I have a client that opens my site with domain url = X in a iframe. But the client's url is different from mine. Once I open my iframe back button works as intended. Can somebody explain whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

see manual http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

```
 <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work :/  Problem is not with the method I am using as I said

Comment: couse it for standart window obj! if need fo iframes use:  
     function navFrame(id, url) {
       var w = document.getElementById(id)
       w.contentWindow.location.replace(url)
      }
 
 or try js framework, like jquery, for crossbrowser support!

Comment: Could you explain me more what navFrame(id,url) does I am new to javascript and whole DOM/iframe/web development , thanks in advance :)

Comment: this function open specific url in iframe by id.  For you problem, you need only  replace "w.contentWindow.location.replace(url)" with "w.contentWindow.history.back()" and it will back history in your iframe.  Just test and you will find solution exactly for you/

Comment: Ye , but the url doesn't change in the iframe. I mean for instance I am on "www.example.com/test" and I am navigating on the site. The content changes but the url stays the same(site url and iframe url). The moment `history.go(-1);` happens to change the site url the button works.